# Foundation Hamburger not Showing

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I tried this but the hamburger is not showing only "Menu". I'm using foundation 6 and tested on Opera, Firefox,Chrome, and Edge.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
        <div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
            <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
                <ul class="title-area">
                   <li class="name"><h1><a href="#"><span>My Website</span></a></h1></li>
                   <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

          <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Foundation gurus any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

here is showing..

please confirm if call to scripts/css is right.

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Foundation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1>
            <a href="#"><span>My Website</span></a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

http://codepen.io/fabiovaz/pen/vLmEVw

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the foundation icons in the app.scss file?
If not add this line:

```
@include foundation-menu-icon;
```